# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined when requiring a library

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 5, I'm trying to use a javascript file that hold some methods that use a library from docuvieware. I ended up using javascript since I was unable to use it on typescript. So I have the following code:

```
const { docuVieware } = require('../../../docuvieware/docuvieware-min');

module.exports = { loadFile: 
    function loadFile(file) {
    if (file != null) {
        var params = {
            Value: file,
            Example: false
        };
        docuVieware.DocuViewareAPI.PostCustomServerAction("DocuVieware1", 
 true, "loadFile", params, function(result){ console.log("result: " + 
 JSON.stringify(result)); });
    }
  }
};
```

But whenever I open my browser I get the following error:

```
> docuvieware-min.js:166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
    at eval (docuvieware-min.js:166)
    at eval (docuvieware-min.js:20)
    at Object.eval (docuvieware-min.js:20)
    at eval (docuvieware-min.js:1128)
    at Object../src/docuvieware/docuvieware-min.js (main.bundle.js:208)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (docuvieware.js:1)
    at Object../src/app/components/detalleExpediente/docuvieware.js (main.bundle.js:128)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (detalleExpediente.component.ts:7)
```

So, if I comment the require line the error disappears but I need it. Any idea why I get this error? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would guess that there is either a bug in `docuVieware` (whatever that is) or your using it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, I have it declared in my angular-cli.json, since using it in the index doesn't work. But when I try to access it from a ts component to make use of its properties, I can't do it. The only way it works is inserting my functions in a script tag in the index.html

Comment: So since I can't access it in ts, I'm trying to make my own javascript repo with all the methods that I need. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Because I need to send some parameters from typescript to those methods, and it becomes a mess if I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because in the file `docuvieware-min.js`, at the line `166`, the `eval` function isn't able to read the property `parse` of an object that doesn't contain it.

More concise : Javascript expects

```
object = {
  parse: function() {...}
};
```

And you provide

```
object = undefined;
```

That's what you can expect when you try to import minified files into your non-minified project.

To use it in typescript, you need to import the definitions file. If you don't know how to, you need to declare your file as a script in your `angular-cli.json` file. Once it's done, the object will be declared as global, hence giving you the right to use it with

```
declare var docuVieware: any;

docuVieware.DocuViewareAPI.PostCustomServerAction(...)
```

Comment: Oh, that's a really good explanation. Thank you very much :D. I already have it in my angular-cli.json, but I can't use the properties in my ts component. Now it works in my js file without requiring the library. I'll keep searching for the use in the ts component. Thank you very much!